# Tcl open a .csv while its open in background

Tags: tcl

I am trying to open a `.csv` file with Tcl for writing, while the file is open for read in background.

```
$ tclsh test.tcl couldn't open "mydata.csv": permission denied
    while executing "open "mydata.csv" a+"
    invoked from within "set f [open "mydata.csv" a+]"
    (file "test.tcl" line 1)
```

**test.tcl**

```
set f [open "mydata.csv" a+]
```

If mydata.csv is open the code fails - otherwise doesn't fail.

How can I open a `.csv` for writing while watching what is being written in realtime?

Comment: Have you tried r+
Open the file for both reading and writing; the file must already exist. You could also perhaps try w+
Open the file for reading and writing. Truncate it if it exists. If it doesn't exist, create a new file I think the issue may be that a+ sets the access line to the end of file

Comment: @jimmy8ball already tried that before posting the question :/

Comment: is this unix based on Windows you are compiling this script?

Comment: Was going to ask the same: is this on Windows? I would be surprised as their is no exclusive locking (simplistically speaking) on OS other than Windows. If on Windows, how do you (open to) read the file exactly?

Comment: @mrcalvin yes it was on windows. Problem was that double clicking opened in write mode with excel. had to navigate to folder and choose **Read-Only** in-order not to harm my program execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was double clicking excel opens in write mode. To be able to inspect the csv, open 
in **Read-Only** mode.

[image]

Comment: Windows as a platform is quite keen on locking open files, especially when they are open read-write (or for execution).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between Tcl and other languages. You can open any file for reading as far as you have got read permissions, but you will only be able to monitor the file content ***as far as it is written to the disk***. Use the read command to check its contents.

For example:

```
set fin [open "mydata.csv" a+]
set fout [open "mydata.csv" r]
read $fout   # shows the file contents
puts -nonewline $fin "something"
read $fout   # nothing to read
flush $fin
read $fout   # reads "something"
```

So you can launch a loop in the background to check $fout regularly.